# Array.from() on IterableIterator seemingly mutates parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm a bit baffled on this one. My code looks like the following:

```js
let matches = code.matchAll(/regex pattern/g);
if (!Array.from(matches).length) {
    matches = code.matchAll(/regex alt pattern/g);
    if (!Array.from(matches).length) return;
}

console.log(Array.from(matches));
```

My goal here is to check for a pattern, and if nothing is found, check for an alternate. If still nothing is found, I want to return, else, I'm going to do some work with it.

My issue here is that `Array.from(matches)` for some reason consumes `matches`. Let's say that the first regex pattern returns a result. The if-statement will be correctly be skipped over, but the console log will print out an empty array. Nothing in `matches`. Same goes for the alternative regex. If I check for that early return, `matches` will be empty again. If I comment it out, however, then that console log has a non-empty array.

According to MDN, `Array.from()` should be making a shallow copy. Why is it instead wiping away that reference?

Comment: I don't want to make this an answer, since I'm not 100% certain of this behaviour in JS. However, *in theory* `Array.from()` will need to iterate your iterator, which will mutate it. If that's right then this is actually expected behaviour. Try using only the value returned by `Array.from(code.matchAll(...))` so that you only use that iterator once.

Comment: According to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#regexp.exec_and_matchall return value of `matchAll()` is "An iterator (which is not a restartable iterable) of matches." so when you iterate over it with `array.from()` it is consumed. The `array.from()` in the if statements are consuming it.

Comment: If you read the MDN doc on what `.matchAll()` returns, it is a non-restartable iterator.  So, you are correct that `Array.from()` will consume it.  You can't do the code that way you are.  Perhaps do `Array.from(matches)` and save it to a variable so you don't need to use the iterator again.

Comment: I didn't think this counted as "restarting", alright then. How am I supposed to do this, just make a copy every time I want to check the value?

Comment: Do `Array.from(matches)` ONCE and save it to a variable.  Then, you can use the array data or the length from the variable whenever you need it without trying to reuse the iterable.

Comment: Well I cannot do it just once, as you'll see in the code snippet, I need to check `matches` twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the MDN doc on what `.matchAll()` returns, it is a non-restartable iterator. So, you are correct that `Array.from()` will consume it and you apparently can't use that iterator again.

So, do the `Array.from(matches)` once and save it to a variable so you aren't trying to use the iterable more than once. Here's one way to do that:

```
let matches = Array.from(code.matchAll(/regex pattern/g));
if (!matches.length) {
    matches = Array.from(code.matchAll(/regex alt pattern/g));
    if (!matches.length) return;
}

console.log(matches);
```